# scheduled job using NetScheduleJobAdd in Active Directory dont run in client

Tags: c++, winapi

i am administrator of Active Directory. i want to copy a executable in the ADMIN$ share location of a client programically. after run my program, executable copy to ADMIN$ share location successfull and when run it, its status in Task Scheduler change to "Running" but executable not run in fact. my program is :

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lmuse.h>
#include <Lmat.h>
#include <lm.h>
#include <string>
#pragma comment(lib, "netapi32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Netapi32.lib")
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif
int main(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
CopyFileW(L"C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\SampleExecutable.exe", L"\\\\192.168.1.5\\ADMIN$\\system32\\MyExecutable.exe", FALSE);

LPTIME_OF_DAY_INFO pBuf = NULL;
NET_API_STATUS nStatus;
LPTSTR pszServerName = NULL;
pszServerName = TEXT("\\\\192.168.1.5");

nStatus = NetRemoteTOD((LPCWSTR)pszServerName,
    (LPBYTE *)&pBuf);
if (nStatus == NERR_Success)
{
    if (pBuf != NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nThe current date is: %d/%d/%d\n",
            pBuf->tod_month, pBuf->tod_day, pBuf->tod_year);
        fprintf(stderr, "The current time is: %d:%d:%d\n",
            pBuf->tod_hours, pBuf->tod_mins, pBuf->tod_secs);


        AT_INFO a_info;

        memset(&a_info, 0, sizeof(a_info));
        a_info.DaysOfMonth = 0;
        a_info.DaysOfWeek = 0;
        a_info.JobTime = 360000; // Run in 12:06:00 AM
        a_info.Command = L"\\\\192.168.1.5\\ADMIN$\\system32\\MyExecutable.exe";
        a_info.Flags = JOB_ADD_CURRENT_DATE;


        DWORD jobid = 0;
        if (NetScheduleJobAdd(TEXT("192.168.1.5"), (LPBYTE)&a_info, &jobid) == NERR_Success)
        {
            MessageBoxA(NULL, "", "", MB_OK);
        }


    }
}
//
// Otherwise, display a system error.
else
    fprintf(stderr, "A system error has occurred: %d\n", nStatus);
//
// Free the allocated buffer.
//program
if (pBuf != NULL)
    NetApiBufferFree(pBuf);

system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Please help me about this problem.
Thanks

Comment: Hi alex, can you detail of "but executable not run in fact"? What's job or function in your MyExecutable.exe?

Comment: Hi Rita, MyExecutable.exe is a simple program for test and only show a message box.